# SQL Server Stored Procedure with cursor to update dynamic tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL server. My requirement is to update table using dynamic SQL using cursor. When I run the procedure, getting succeeded message. But not getting result. Please find the code below and help me to fix issue.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Update(@IN_TABLENAME VARCHAR)
AS
  DECLARE @v_tblname NVARCHAR(50),
    @v_existing_column NVARCHAR(50),
    @v_new_column NVARCHAR(50),
    @v_key      INTEGER,
    @SQLString NVARCHAR(2000)

  DECLARE TblCur CURSOR FOR
      SELECT TblNAME, CURR_COLUMN, NEW_COLUMN, Seq_KEY FROM CONTROL_Table
      WHERE
        TblNAME=@IN_TABLENAME

    OPEN TblCur FETCH NEXT FROM TblCur
    INTO @v_tblname, @v_existing_column, @v_new_column,  @v_key

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @SQLString = N'UPDATE @v_tblname SET @v_new_column = ReferenceTable.NewColumn FROM @v_tblname INNER JOIN ReferenceTable ON ReferenceTable.OldColumn =@v_tblname.@v_existing_column'
   Print @SQLString
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
  ,N'@v_tblname NVARCHAR(50)'
  ,N'@v_new_column NVARCHAR(50)'
  ,N'@v_existing_column NVARCHAR(50)'
  ,@v_tblname, @v_new_column, @v_existing_column
  FETCH NEXT FROM TblCur INTO @v_tblname, @v_existing_column, @v_new_column, @v_key
END -- End of Fetch
CLOSE TblCur
DEALLOCATE TblCur
```

Answer (score 0):

This just isn't going to work like this at all. You can't pass the table name as a parameter in dynamic sql. You will have to build your dynamic sql correctly. I love that you are trying to use parameterized sql but in this case it isn't possible. You also need to read this article before you use the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

When doing an update with a join you need to update the alias instead of the table name. It will sometimes confused about which row(s) to update. I also wrapped all the object names with QUOTENAME in case they have spaces or other such challenging names.

You also have a @v_key variable but it was never used in your update statement. I suspect you want that but I don't really know.

I obviously can't come close to testing this but this should be pretty close.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Update(@IN_TABLENAME VARCHAR)
AS
  DECLARE @v_tblname NVARCHAR(50),
    @v_existing_column NVARCHAR(50),
    @v_new_column NVARCHAR(50),
    @v_key      INTEGER,
    @SQLString NVARCHAR(2000)

  DECLARE TblCur CURSOR FOR
      SELECT TblNAME, CURR_COLUMN, NEW_COLUMN, Seq_KEY FROM CONTROL_Table
      WHERE
        TblNAME=@IN_TABLENAME

    OPEN TblCur FETCH NEXT FROM TblCur
    INTO @v_tblname, @v_existing_column, @v_new_column,  @v_key

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       SET @SQLString = N'UPDATE ut SET ' + QUOTENAME(@v_new_column) + ' = ReferenceTable.NewColumn '
        + 'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@v_tblname) + ' ut '
        + 'INNER JOIN ReferenceTable ON ReferenceTable.OldColumn = ut.' + QUOTENAME(@v_existing_column)
       Print @SQLString
      EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
      FETCH NEXT FROM TblCur INTO @v_tblname, @v_existing_column, @v_new_column, @v_key
    END -- End of Fetch
CLOSE TblCur
DEALLOCATE TblCur
```